# Capitalisation conventions for code references in comments

Tags: c#, .net, comments, naming-conventions, naming

According to C# naming guidelines my code would look like this: `Patient.Id`. `Id` is in Pascal case because it's an abbreviation for "Identity". However in an English sentence it should be written as "ID".

How would I write this in my XML comments?

1. `The patient ID.` (Sounds like "patient" is an adjective.)
2. `The patient&apos;s ID.` (Seems the most grammatically correct and fit for the comment section but `Id` is a surrogate key and not part of the business logic. No where in the end-user documentation is there any mention of "ID".)
3. `The <c>Patient<c>&apos;s ID` (Sounds weird unless I make it `The <c>Patient<c> object's ID.` but that's too long to write everywhere.)
4. `The <c>Patient<c>&apos;s <c>Id</c>` (Sounds technically wrong since `Id` is a variable and not a custom `class`.)

Comment: I wouldn't disagree with #1, as ID is essentially an attribute of Patient, making it a part of describing a Patient, therefore "adjective" is not entirely wrong (if you turn it around a bit from what you said).

Comment: @DonBoitnott That only sounds right when spoken alound since you mentally put quotes around "patient ID" when you hear it, but when written down there should be only one possible interpretation.

Comment: I wouldn't argue your point.

Comment: @DonBoitnott There is probably multi-threaded code where asynchronous objects are described as being patient.